# Tkinter Labels going outside window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to see different fonts and how they look in tkinter but they are going outside the window. I saw other answers on this and how to add a scrollbar but none of them are working. So is there a way I can add a scrollbar in my app or any other solution so I can view all Fonts.

Thanks

This is my code

```py
from tkinter import Tk, font, Label
root = Tk()
x = font.families()
for i in x:
    l = Label(root, text=i, font=(i, 12))
    l.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Can someone pls help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a scrollbar to a group of widgets in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085696/adding-a-scrollbar-to-a-group-of-widgets-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
from tkinter import Tk, font, Label
root = Tk()
row=0
col=0
x = font.families()
for i in x:
    l = Label(text=i, font=(i, 10))
    l.grid(column=col,row=row)
    row+=1
    if row>23:
        row=0
        col+=1
root.mainloop()
```

---

#### Updated

You can add scroll Bar to the window(*'Its a bit complicated'*).

```
from tkinter import Tk, font, Label, Frame, Canvas, Scrollbar
root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)


rCanvas = Canvas(frame)

rCanvas.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)


scrollBar = Scrollbar(frame,command=rCanvas.yview)
scrollBar.pack(side='right', fill='y')


rCanvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollBar.set)

sFrame = Frame(master=rCanvas)
sFrame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: rCanvas.configure(scrollregion=rCanvas.bbox("all")))

rCanvas.create_window((0,0), window=sFrame,anchor="nw")


x = font.families()
for i in x:
    l = Label(sFrame, text=i, font=(i, 12))
    l.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: The labels are still going outside from right side

Comment: I don't know. How to add a scrollbar to the window but I give my 100% to this question.

Comment: But on my side this will work perfectly.

Comment: You can see this image.

Comment: I think your problem is your monitor display size.

Comment: yeah i will try it out